# Go get isn't using the GOPROXY for sum.golang.org

Tags: go

I'm working in a company, so we need to work with a proxy.
That's why we are using a GOPROXY, which works fine in our Openshift builds.
However, if I try to set up Go on my working, machine I always get an error when trying to execute `go get`.

I've set up the GOPROXY env on my local machine.
I get the following output:

```
go get -x -v k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/k8s.io/@v/v0.19.0.info
go: downloading k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/k8s.io/client-go/@v/v0.19.0.zip
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/k8s.io/@v/v0.19.0.info: 404 Not Found (0.059s)
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/k8s.io/client-go/@v/v0.19.0.zip: 200 OK (0.053s)
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/sumdb/sum.golang.org/supported
# get http://GOPROXY_URL/sumdb/sum.golang.org/supported: 404 Not Found (0.017s)
# get https://sum.golang.org/lookup/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0
# get https://sum.golang.org/lookup/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
go get k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: verifying module: k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
go get k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: verifying module: k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0: Get "https://sum.golang.org/lookup/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.0": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I did two wireshark captures, on on the openshift node and one local and I noticed that on openshift he always goes over our GOPROXY, which isn't the case on my machine.

Comment: What version of Go is on each machine?

Comment: Did you use `.netrc` or `git credential.helper` to connect `GOPROXY`?

Comment: I'm using the latest go version  1.15.5.

Comment: No I'm not using any git credentials, the GOPROXY is public.